# Semigroup associated to a Markov process

Tags: markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I'm studying the transition semigroup associated to a Markov Process,
in particular the Hille-Yosida theorem and the Martingale Problem. In my notes I found : "If $\{T_t\}_t$ is a strongly continuous semigroup then there exist a unique Markov process with that given transition semigroup". Why?

In general, if I have a transition semigroup, how can I construct the Markov process associated?

Comment: The semigroup of $X_t$ is the family of operators $P_t$ where $(P_t f)(x)=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$. Just speaking formally, $(P_t 1_A)(x)=E[1_A(X_t)|X_0=x]=P(X_t \in A | X_0=x)$. So this would define the probability transition function for the Markov process. Is $1_A$ in the domain of $P_t$? If not, can you approximate it appropriately to infer the probability transition function anyway?

Comment: On which space are the operators $T_t$ defined?

Comment: @Ian  $P_t \colon B_b(E) \to B_b(E)$ where $B_b(E)$ is the set of Borel and Bounded function on an Euclidean space E.  The problem is that the transition function doesn't identify a unique Markov Process. If I have a Markov process, I  can associate a transition function but I think that the converse doesn't hold...Thank you for your attention

Comment: @saz $P_t \colon B_b(E) \to B_b(E)$

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Comment: @Ian Can you approximate $\mathbb{1}_A$ when the domain of $P_t$ is $C_0(E,\mathbb{R})$?