# Definition of Markov operator

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I'm looking for a motivation and standard definition of Markov operators. Sources online seem elusive, and I've seen several definitions:

**definition 1**:
[Here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/where-does-markov-operator-come-from) is one, saying $P$ is an operator on the space of $L^1(\mu)$ functions that

1. preserves nonnegativity
2. and such that $\int (Pf)(x) \mu(dx) = \int f(x) \mu(dx) \;\;\; \text{ for any } f\in L^1(\mu).$

I interpret this integral-preserving property as "the Markov transition maintains the same total probability" on the state space.

**definition 2**: [Here](https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/2006-17-05/S1061-0022-06-00928-9/S1061-0022-06-00928-9.pdf) a Markov operator is defined as any operator on $L^2(X,\mu)$ that is

1. a contraction,
2. sending the identity to one,
3. preserving nonnegativity.

Why is this now defined on $L^2$? Since the overlap of $L^1$ and $L^2$ functions is not that simple, there must be a fundamental difference in the definition. And is property 2 of definition 1 somehow equivalent to properties 1 and 2 of definition 2?

**Related?**: I believe Markov operators are closely related to the [infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) of a stochastic process, given by
$$ Af(x) = \lim_{t\downarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X_t) | X_0=x] - f(x)}{t}.$$

Is this a type of Markov operator? (The infinitesimal generator is also an operator on measurable functions).

**What's the equivalence between these two definitions** and what's the intuition of why we need Markov operators? Furthermore, what's the point of defining it for **all** $L^1$ or $L^2$ functions?

Comment: $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a semigroup, the latter being the transition semigroup. Namely $P=e^A$

Comment: @Chaos $P = e^A$ is a Markov operator? Is this the definition or a special case?

Comment: In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359261/build-a-markov-process-from-a-transition-semigroup) question I see $P_tf(x):=\int_E f(y)p(t,x,dy)=\mathbb E (f(X^x_t))$ but I'm not sure how (or whether) the first "=" is equivalent to $P= e^A$

Comment: Read through 1.2.1 Markov Semigroups, Invariant Measures in "Analysis and Geometry of Markov Diffusion Operators" of Bakry et al.